# React-native navigation is it possible to intercept the back action?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to  intercept the back action in react native on any route?
Lets say I am on a page and I want navigate a user on a different route when he/she performs a back action.

or even a popup confirm.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler

Answer (score 0):

You can use React's [BackHandler][1] for instance

```
// import the back handler from react-native
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native'

// fire the listener on every render (including the componentWillUnmount)
useLayoutEffect(() => {
   BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
     {
       console.warn('about to go back....')
     }
    );
}, [])


  [1]: https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler
```